# Detect AM/PM vs 24 hr clock preference from Java Locale information?

Tags: java, localization, internationalization

I am looking for a way to tell in a Java program if a particular locale prefers display of time in 12 hour AM/PM or in 24 hour clock.  Now, normally I would just use DateFormat to properly format the date as appropriate for the Locale.  However, I'm attempting to localize a stem-and-leaf calendar display of transit schedules which requires some direct knowledge of the locale preferences.  You can see an example of a schedule here:

http://onebusaway.org/where/standard/schedule.action?id=1_538

Any ideas on how I can detect 12 hour AM/PM vs 24 hour programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probe it, like this:

```
boolean hasAmPmClock(Locale locale) {
        DateFormat stdFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
                Locale.US);
        DateFormat localeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG,
                locale);
        String midnight = "";
        try {
            midnight = localeFormat.format(stdFormat.parse("12:00 AM"));
        } catch (ParseException ignore) {
        }
        return midnight.contains("12");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way that's a little less roundabout than the accepted answer:

```
DateFormat format;
// ...
boolean is24Hour;
if (format instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat)format;
    String pattern = sdf.toPattern();
    is24Hour = !pattern.contains("a");
}
```

Still pretty gross, and it won't work with other `DateFormat` concrete types, but the standard ways of getting a `DateFormat` object seem to return `SimpleDateFormat`.